# How can we modify the ER diagrams using DBeaver

Tags: entity-relationship, dbeaver

I already have ER diagrams with me which are updated version a month ago. Meanwhile, there are some schema changes happened in the database. How do I can merge those changes using DBeaver or what are the alternate options to merge those changes.

Comment: I have the same question. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

To update an existing ER diagram to reflect subsequent changes made to the schema, follow these steps:

1. Ensure that the `.erd` file tab is selected
2. Click `File > Refresh` in the options bar on the top-left (or hit `F5`)

Keep in mind that you can't undo this change, and the layout of the elements in the diagram will be rearranged.

This was tested with `DBeaver Version 21.1.5.202108160727`